# Efficiently updating columns in a Class in Python

Tags: python, class

I have a class in Python which takes in a dataset, and I have columns in this dataset which need to be converted from strings to floats. Since every function inside this class needs these columns in float format I was wondering if there was an efficient way to update these columns without having to convert them from string to float in each function.

For example, my code looks similar to this:

```
class xyz():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def xyzf1(self, data):
        data["sales"] = pd.to_numeric(data["sales"])
        data["prices"] = pd.to_numeric(data["prices"])
        data["client"] = pd.to_numeric(data["client"])
        ...

    def xyzf2(self, data):
        data["sales"] = pd.to_numeric(data["sales"])
        data["prices"] = pd.to_numeric(data["prices"])
        data["client"] = pd.to_numeric(data["client"])
        ...

    def xyzf3(self, data):
        data["sales"] = pd.to_numeric(data["sales"])
        data["prices"] = pd.to_numeric(data["prices"])
        data["client"] = pd.to_numeric(data["client"])
        ...
```

Basically, I wanted to know if there's a neater way of converting the "sales" column to a numeric column without having to include that line in every single function inside the class.

Comment: You call the functions `xyzf1`, `xyzf2` etc while passing along the data. Instead of converting it each time after passing the data to the function, can you not just convert it once before calling the functions? Where is `data` actually stored?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Honestly, I don't really know yet (in fact I barely know much beyond what I was told to do), the only thing I was told was to try and 'automate' as much as possible and ensure very little additional work needed to be done. As such, I wanted to do all conversions etc. in the class I'm writing...

Comment: Without seeing more of the code I can only guess. But, perhaps consider containing all the data within the `__init__` (it looks like that's what you are doing already). Then, in the `__init__` you can called the `to_numeric` on that data. Then, instead of passing the data to the functions, you can access it within the functions as `self.data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full functionality of OOPS is not properly used in the code

Instead of passing the data to individual methods in the class, pass the argument directly to the class and perform the preprocessing. This can be done by using the `__init__()` method

The data can be used in the class methods by using `self.data`

```
class xyz():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.data["sales"] = pd.to_numeric(self.data["sales"])

    def xyzf1(self):
        #for example if you want to get the first row in the dataset
        first_row = self.data.iloc[0] 
        
        return first_row
        ...

    def xyzf2(self):
        #for example if you want to get the second row in the dataset
        second_row = self.data.iloc[0] 
        
        return second_row
        ...

    def xyzf3(self):
        ...

instance = xyz(data)
row1 = instance.xyzf1()
row2 = instance.xyzf2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think that type of data is dict (cause you use the **key** "sales"). Am I correct? May be no, because I didn`t work with pandas (may be it is a specificity of pandas).

Return to subjest. May be my version will tell you something:

```py
class xyz():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {"sales": "222"}
        self.data["sales"] = int(self. data["sales"])

    def xyzf1(self, data):
        print(type(self.data["sales"]))

    def xyzf2(self, data):
        print(type(self.data["sales"]))

    def xyzf3(self, data):
        print(type(self.data["sales"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {"sales": "111"}
    x = xyz()
    x.xyzf1(data)   # <class 'int'>
    x.xyzf2(data)   # <class 'int'>
    x.xyzf3(data)   # <class 'int'>
    print(data["sales"])    # 111
```

Comment: Ah, unfortunately the data is actually a gigantic dataframe, not a dictionary. I only included one line because I didn't want to make things too confusing. I will edit the code I wrote to clear up that misconception. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: OK.


`def __init__(self, data):`
        `self.data = [] # define default values here`
        `for item in data:`
            `self.data[item] = pd.to_numeric(self.data[item])`

Comment: I mean that you can do it in class initializer